# How to get the value of a data attribute from view to controller in Laravel 5.7?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I'm trying to send the value of a data attribute of an input tag other than the `value` attribute itself from view to controller through the `http` request, i tried using hidden `input` tag but the problem is the input tag i'm trying to send is an `option` tag, so adding a hidden input tag after the option tag breaks my dropdown list.

this is the code:

```
<select class="form-control" name="parent">
   <?php
     $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=dbhost.dev;dbname=sdi;charset=utf8', 'sdiuser', 'sdiuser');
     if(Auth::user()->usertype=="super"){
         $sql = "SELECT * FROM capteurs where type like 'groupe'";}
     else {
         $sql = "SELECT * FROM capteurs where type like 'groupe' and etab like ".Auth::user()->etab;
           }
     $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
     $stmt->execute();
     $groups = $stmt->fetchAll();
       foreach($groups as $group): ?>
         <option id="parent" value="<?= $group['id']; ?>" data-etab="{{$group['etab']}}" name="parent">
         <?= $group['code_capteur']; ?>
         </option>
         <input name="group-etab" type="hidden" value="{{$group['etab']}}"/>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: which hidden input tag you are passing?

Comment: edited the original post, sorry!

Comment: In laravel, you shouldn't be declaring a PDO object.  You should be using Eloquent or Query Builder.

Comment: I know, this is more of a learning project for me and i realized i should be using Eloquent, next project no PDO will be used though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to add it to the value attribute, then parse it in the handler, for example:

```
<option id="parent" value="<?= $group['id'] . '|' . $group['etab']; ?>" name="parent">
```

Then in php (this is just for brevity, you should still properly sanitize inputs):

```
$array = explode('|', $_REQUEST['parent']);
$id = $array[0];
$etab = $array[1];
```

Comment: The `json_encode` option given by Aditya Thakur is probably a better way to do it.

Comment: That's what i did before coming to find out that you answered the same thing!

Comment: I'm not comfortable with working with JSON, thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
@foreach($groups as $group): ?>
<option id="parent" value="{{json_encode(['id' => $group['id'], 'etab' => $group['etab']])}}" >
    <?= $group['code_capteur']; ?>
</option>
@endforeach
```

then at the controller, you can just

```
$data = json_decode($request->input('parent'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to create an input hidden with javascript, you can set the hidden value with the selected value.
Regards